# Problems using UIPanGestureRecognizer in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a UIPanGestureRecognizer in my UITableViewController to use for a swipe to delete animation. Similar to the swipe to delete used in the Clear app, where if you swipe a UITableViewCell in left or right the cell moves and gets deleted.

I have tried implementing this in my UITableViewCell subclass but it never seems to receive the event.

This is the code I put in my UITableViewCell subclass to try this functionality. In my init method

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and then the methods to handle it:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self.superview];
//might have to change view to tableView
//check for the horizontal gesture
if (fabsf(translation.x) > fabsf(translation.y)) {
    return YES;
    NSLog(@"Panning");
}
return NO;
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //if the gesture has just started record the center location
    NSLog(@"handlePan");
    _originalCenter = self.center; //Declared as a CGPoint at the top of my TableViewCell
}

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    //translate the center (aka translate from the center of the cell)
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    self.center = CGPointMake(_originalCenter.x + translation.x, _originalCenter.y);
    // determine whether the item has been dragged far enough to delete/complete

}

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    // the frame this cell would have had before being dragged
    CGRect originalFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.frame = originalFrame;}
     ];
}
}
```

The Cells don't move at all though. Not really sure what's going on here

Comment: does this get executed? NSLog(@"handlePan");

Comment: also move NSLog(@"panning") above the return statement so that it will get outputted.

Comment: Neither of the logs execute. I'm not really sure what's going on. The cells are all completely fixed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't want the cell's swipe gesture to happen simultaneously with the table view scroll gesture, then add a pan gesture to your cell and make it a delegate:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doPan:)];
pan.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

And implement the following delegate method to only start if the pan is horizontal:

```
#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    // note: we might be called from an internal UITableViewCell long press gesture

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;
        UIView *cell = [panGestureRecognizer view];
        CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:[cell superview]];

        // Check for horizontal gesture
        if (fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y))
        {
            return YES;
        }

    }

    return NO;
}
```

Swift3 ..

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // do not use, say, layoutSubviews as layoutSubviews is called often
    let p = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourPan))
    p.delegate = self
    contentView.addGestureRecognizer(p)
    }
}

override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ g: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if (g.isKind(of: UIPanGestureRecognizer.self)) {
        let t = (g as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).translation(in: contentView)
        let verticalness = abs(t.y)
        if (verticalness > 0) {
            print("ignore vertical motion in the pan ...")
            print("the event engine will >pass on the gesture< to the scroll view")
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: @JoeBlow: Looks good. One comment: `layoutSubviews` can be called multiple times, so you would have multiple gesture recognizers added which is probably not a good thing.

Comment: thanks a million for that tip, @jasonMoore.Sending a bounty!

Comment: wow  this is very helpful!!   But for in swift 4,  I think this function gestureRe..shouldbegin has been changed for a little but that it no longer overrides any super methods.

Comment: Works like a charm with swift 4!

Answer (score 13):

You need the following method in order for the gesture to be detected in sync with the scrollView's panGesture:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
   return YES; //otherGestureRecognizer is your custom pan gesture
}
```

Remember to set the panGesture.delegate to your viewController. (Updated with OlivaresF's comment.)

Comment: This worked for me. Remember to set your viewController as the panGestureRecognizer delegate, so this method is actually called.


Also, if you do this, your pan recognizer will fire when the user is scrolling the tableView, so you should be prepared for that.

Comment: This is basically **not, really, correct**.  You pass the gesture through to the scroll engine; you don't really "want them both" (which would be a bit of a mess, in almost all of use cases).  Jason's answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: You're assuming the OP doesn't want both gestures recognizing at the same time. I agree that Jason's answer is correct if you want the gesture recognizers to be distinct, but that doesn't mean that my answer is wrong.

Comment: Hi @Mark - actually you're totally correct. I think it would be pretty unusual in iOS to have them both recognized, but you are 1000% correct.  Nice one.  Thanks for that great tip.

Answer (score 0):

Add the gesture recognizer to the content view.

```
[self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Comment: Do I do this within the `init` method of the UITableViewCell subclass? EDIT: added this code to the `init` method and still not getting anything.

Comment: The `Panning` log now comes up in the console, but only after holding down the cell for a second. What I'm hoping I can make it so a user doesn't have to hold it down for a second but can just swipe and it would work.